# Plot joint return period

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability, scatter-plot, probability-distribution

I have two variables var1 and var2. I want to have joint return period plot of two variables like[image]

The blue line indicates the joint return period of two variables and the number indicate the return period value in years(1,5,10,50,...).

I am not sure how to generate this plot.

```
set.seed(101)
dates = seq(as.Date("1951-12-31"),as.Date("2000-12-31"),by="day")
var1 = rnorm(length(dates), 0.5)
var2 = rnorm(length(dates),5)
plot(var1,var2,cex=0.1)
```

Could anyone help me with this?